# How to get mobile numbers if my android phone have two SIM cards?

Tags: android, serial-number, dual-sim

I have implemented an application for get the SIM cards mobile numbers from my Google Ebony QWERTY touchscreen.In this device i have two SIM cards.I have used TelephonyManager for get mobile number from device as follows

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) arTnewActivity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String getSimSerialNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
Log.v("Device mobile numbers",getSimSerialNumber);
```

From the above code it will return a single mobile number but If i run in case of Ebony QWERTY dual sim phone then can i get two sim card serial numbers?

please any body help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand the default SDK does not have support to handle dual sim. From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626575/dual-sim-change-default-sim-card) it sounds like you have to ask the manufacturer if they have a special SDK that could provide this.

If it's Google they might have some additional SDK stuffed away somewhere? :-)