# Programmatically disable SIM slot

Tags: android, android-widget, dual-sim

I have dual sim phone and I need to write a widget that will disable first or second SIM card. Is there any way to do this?

**Edit:**
I found questions

1) [Dual SIM card Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255147/dual-sim-card-android)

2) [Dual-SIM Change Default SIM card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626575/dual-sim-change-default-sim-card)

3) [dual sim android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382971/dual-sim-android-sdk)

The situation is disappointing.

Comment: i think you need rooted device for this.