# get or set selected default sim card if the user has a dual sim

Tags: android, android-sms, android-subscriptionmanager

I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626575/dual-sim-change-default-sim-card) from 2012 and it has outdated answers. Until around 2015 Android natively supported multiple sim cards in API 22.

[image]

I heard about [SubscriptionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html) but I am not quite familiar with it, how can I get and dynamically set the currently selected Sim for SMS messages?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select sim for sending sms only, you can try this post [How to send a SMS using SMSmanager in Dual SIM mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351936/how-to-send-a-sms-using-smsmanager-in-dual-sim-mobile) where you need not interact with android settings but can send sms directly with java code.

Comment: Hi! Thank you, I don't really like using reflection as there is no guarantee that it will work on every device.